# Prevent relative divs from overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-position

Basically the bar div of arrows is currently overlapping with the title div.  I'd like the bar div to be underneath the title div.

I understand that since the name and rectangle divs are absolutely positioned, they are not taking up space as they normally would, but I don't know how to make the bar div appear underneath the title div. An easy fix would be to give the bar sufficient top margin or padding until it is positioned underneath the title div, but this seems like a bad way of doing it. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dannyp32/9kYVL/)

HTML

```
<div>NAME</div>

<div class="title">
    <div class="name">JOHNATHAN DOE</div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>

<div class="bar">
    <a class="step" href="#">
        <div class="arrowEnd"></div>
        <div class="arrow">some stuff</div>
        <div class="arrowPointer"></div>
    </a>
    <a class="step" href="#">
        <div class="arrowEnd"></div>
        <div class="arrow">some stuff</div>
        <div class="arrowPointer"></div>
    </a>
    <a class="step" href="#">
        <div class="arrowEnd"></div>
        <div class="arrow">some stuff</div>
        <div class="arrowPointer"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.rectangle {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background: red;
}
.name {
    font-size: 3em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.arrow {
    width: 28%;
    height: 24px;
    background: #777777;
}

.arrowPointer {
    border-left: 12px solid #777777;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    font-size: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    width: 0;
}

.arrowEnd{
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-top: 12px solid #777777;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #777777;
    border-right: 12px solid #777777;
    font-size: 0; 
    line-height: 0; 
    width: 0;
}

.bar > a > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, why are you positioning the name absolutely when it's going to be the first thing on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning by definition is placed based on the specified coordinates in the CSS. If you're looking to place the bar below the title, make it 'relative'. If there's a reason why you're not wishing to make it relative, there may be a way to go around that.

Additionally, making your stylesheet based on relative positioning is also really helpful when you're looking to resize your window, view the website on a different device, or view the website on a screen of a different resolution and/or DPI.

EDIT Answer:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gUd4/)
Use the `Clear:both` to bring your div below another while keeping both of them as relative positioning.

Comment: When the bar is positioned relatively it does not fix the issue. The bar still appears overlapped over the title div. http://jsfiddle.net/dannyp32/9kYVL/1/

Comment: I think I understand your problem better now. The reason why that is happening is because Absolute Positioning is relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. Try setting your `name` div to relative and see if that helps.

Comment: So yes, I understand that setting the name to static will allow the bar to be positioned underneath it. But I have the name positioned absolutely because I'd like to have name and rectangle divs positioned  on opposite sides at the same vertical position. When I set the name to be static, it also pushes down the rectangle to be underneath the name.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want the word 'Name' and the rectangle on the same line, 'John Doe' on the second line, and the arrow bars on the third line, correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!